# Required parameters exception doesn't work in spring boot 2.x

Tags: spring, spring-boot, exception

In my spring boot application, I tried to handled the **Required parameter** exception. This question may be duplicated. But the answers posted don't help me.

My controller

```
 @GetMapping("/test")
    public ObjectId test(@RequestBody OIdLGroupIds OIdLGroupIds,@RequestParam ObjectId _id){
        return videoService.test();
    }
```

My global exception handler is like following.

```
@RestControllerAdvice
public class GlobalExceptionHandler extends ResponseEntityExceptionHandler {

@ExceptionHandler(Exception.class)
public final ResponseEntity<Object> handleAllExceptions(Exception ex, WebRequest request) {
    List<String> details = new ArrayList<>();
    details.add(ex.getLocalizedMessage());
    ErrorResponse error = new ErrorResponse("Server Error", details);
    return new ResponseEntity(error, HttpStatus.INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR);
}

@ExceptionHandler(NotFoundHandler.class)
public final ResponseEntity<Object> handleRecordNotFoundException(NotFoundHandler ex, WebRequest request) {

    Map<String, Object> body = new LinkedHashMap<>();
    body.put("timestamp", LocalDateTime.now());
    body.put("message", "Record not found");

    List<String> details = new ArrayList<>();
    details.add(ex.getLocalizedMessage());
    ErrorResponse error = new ErrorResponse("Record Not Found", details);
    return new ResponseEntity(error, HttpStatus.NOT_FOUND);
}

@Override
protected ResponseEntity<Object> handleMethodArgumentNotValid(
        MethodArgumentNotValidException ex, HttpHeaders headers,
        HttpStatus status, WebRequest request) {

    Map<String, Object> body = new LinkedHashMap<>();
    body.put("timestamp", LocalDate.now());
    body.put("status", status.value());

    Set<String> errors = ex.getBindingResult()
            .getFieldErrors()
            .stream()
            .map(x -> x.getDefaultMessage())
            .collect(Collectors.toSet());

    body.put("details", errors);

    return new ResponseEntity<>(body, HttpStatus.BAD_REQUEST);
    }
}
```

It doesn't throw any details (Body is blank). But the response status is `400 Bad Request`. **But when I comment all above codes, it throws default exceptions with body.**

I tried this also

```
@Override
protected ResponseEntity<Object> handleMissingServletRequestParameter(MissingServletRequestParameterException ex, HttpHeaders headers, HttpStatus status, WebRequest request) {
        String name = ex.getParameterName();
        System.out.println(name);
        logger.error(name + " parameter is missing");

        return super.handleMissingServletRequestParameter(ex, headers, status, request);
    }
```

I have tried in many ways, But no luck. Did I miss anything? Please help me. Thanks in advance.

Comment: did you get your answer yet? I have the same situation to validate request parameter , but doesn't work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Empty request body raises `HttpMessageNotReadableException`.

```
@RestControllerAdvice
public class GlobalExceptionHandler extends ResponseEntityExceptionHandler {

    @Override
    protected ResponseEntity<Object> handleMissingServletRequestParameter(MissingServletRequestParameterException ex,
        HttpHeaders headers, HttpStatus status, WebRequest request) {
        String name = ex.getParameterName();
        System.out.println(name);
        logger.error(name + " parameter is missing");

        return super.handleMissingServletRequestParameter(ex, headers, status, request);
    }

    @Override
    protected ResponseEntity<Object> handleHttpMessageNotReadable(
        HttpMessageNotReadableException ex, HttpHeaders headers, HttpStatus status, WebRequest request) {
        System.out.println(ex.getMessage());
        logger.error("Request body is missing");

        return super.handleHttpMessageNotReadable(ex,  headers, status, request);
    }

}
```

If you allow empty body, use `@RequestBody(required = false)`.